# SQL Performing self join to retrieve the current and the immediate previous record by date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've been trying to retrieve the current and previous record as a single row. I need to get the immediate record before the current one to compare the location of both rows.

```
Select 
    CurrentMovement.Location, CurrentMovement.EffectiveDate
  , PreviousMovement.Location, PreviousMovement.EffectiveDate 
From Product product
Inner join ProductMovement CurrentMovement ON product.Id = CurrentMovement.ProductId
    And CurrentMovement.EffectiveDate = (Select Max(EffectiveDate)
                                         From ProductMovement
                                         Where ProductId = product.ProductId)
Inner join ProductMovement PreviousMovement ON PreviousMovement.ProductId = CurrentMovement.ProductId
    And PreviousMovement.EffectiveDate < CurrentMovement.EffectiveDate
Where CurrentMovement.Locations != PreviousMovement.Location
```

I was able to retrieve the current record on the CurrentMovement inner join.

The problem is determining the previous record on the next inner join as I need to retrieve the Max(EffectiveDate) of the previous records that are less than the CurrentMovement.EffectiveDate.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to assign sequential row numbers and join using this row number. Like so:

```
WITH PM AS(
    SELECT *
        , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC)
    FROM ProductMovement
)
Select 
    PMC.Location, PMC.EffectiveDate
  , PMP.Location, PMP.EffectiveDate 
From Product AS P
    INNER join PM AS PMC
        ON P.Id = PMC.ProductId
        AND PMC.RN = 1
    LEFT JOIN PM ON PMP
        ON P.Id= PMP.ProductId
        AND PMP.RN - 1 = PMC.RN
```

---

Comment: Thank you for answering my inquiry. I am a little concern about the performance of the query as the record on the ProductMovement table can reach millions in a couple of days. It might not be ideal for larger database records. I will try it though. Thanks again

Comment: If it's a problem make sure to have an index on ProductMovement, either clustered with ProductId and EffectiveDate as key or non clustered with same key but make sure to include Location as well